# Inside our Details List View; can we show 3 tabs to show a Parent list item, Child-1 list item and Child-2 list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, list-view, modern-experience

We have a SharePoint online communication site, and it contains these 3 custom lists:

1. Master List
2. Child-1 List which contain a lookup column to the Master list
3. Child-2 List which contain a lookup column to the Master list.

Now we are trying to achieve the following:

1. When the user select/click on a Master list's item inside the build-in list view >> to show the following screen, which have 3 tabs; Master,Child-1 & Child-2, as follow:

[image]

When you click on each tab the related list item/s should be shown (the master should be the list item the user clicks on + the Child-1 & Child-2 should be retrieved based on the lookup field).

So is this something we can achieve in SharePoint online? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact design (tabs & side panel) is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilites.

You have to use the custom solution for this requirement.

**Possible solutions**

1. Form customization using Power Apps:

   You can customize SharePoint list forms using Power Apps & design tabs & fetch/filter child list items using Power Apps capabilities.
2. SPFx List view command set:

   You can develop a list view command set using SPFx & show details of current list item as well as child list items on side panel/dialog. You have more control on look & feel (UI) in this case as it involves custom coding.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, so which approach you prefer and why?

Comment: As a developer I prefer list view command set as it gives more control for coding. You can show dialogs/popup with tabs UI as you want. Also, no need to customize SP default list forms. With Power Apps approach, you have limited options for using controls (button/text, etc.) & not much control over UI. But, it might work for you if you want to build this quickly using drag n drop controls.